# Calling MessageBox.Show from a separate form

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I'm wondering today if there is any way to show a messagebox with a separate form as it's parent. As an example, say I have Form1 and Form2. From Form1, how do I call a messagebox to show with Form2 as the parent? In my case, Form2 is dynamically created, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a `Form` instance as the first parameter to `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: Like this? `MessageBox.Show(Form2, "foo")`

Comment: never knew about it + 1

Comment: @JordanFitz: You need to pass an _instance_.

Comment: @SLaks this is essentially what Form2 is `Form Form2 = new Form();`

Comment: @JordanFitz: Then that will work.  However, making an instance with the same name as a class is generally a bad idea.  Also, use an names; rename `Form1` and `Form2`.

Comment: @SLaks Those aren't the actual names I'm using. The actual names are Form_Main and the dynamically created one is called displayForm.